# Word docs from iCloud Drive just Read-Only

Tags: ios, icloud, ms-office

I moved a bunch of Word documents from a Windows PC to an iCloud Drive. On an iPad I have a working Office subscription for the Office Suite. I can create new Word files just fine, but when I open one of the older Word files, there a just Read-Only. I just can duplicate the files and then start I can edit the new old file.

Comment: Does this help - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unlock-a-file-that-has-been-locked-for-editing-bdda0d41-1b8e-44ed-a6ae-6d095d37c22d ?

Comment: If the above doesn't help, this seems to be some sort of bug With MS Office as many others are complaining about it too - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_imobile-mso_365hp/how-to-stop-read-only-on-word-docs-on-ipad/107ca2b9-9f24-4d64-94fb-d664be01e18d#?page=1